# Share product on facebook 1.9

Tags: css, facebook, social

I'm using Magento CE 1.9 and I just tried to share a product on facebook. Worked like a charm except all the css of the text block was included :(

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to fix this? Thanks.

Attached: Screenshot of problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have send descrition

```
Used $this->htmlEscape() for you variable to remove html tag from string
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp

Edit: change

```
urlencode(trim($_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description')));
```

to

`urlencode(trim($this->htmlEscape($_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description'))));`

**Edit**:use `basic php function strip_tags  to remove all html tag from string`

```
 urlencode(trim( strip_tags($_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description'))));
```

Comment: Which file should I edit this in? Sorry but I am not very familiar with Magento. Thanks.

Comment: app\design\frontend\yourpackage\yourtemplate\template\catalog\product\view\sharing.phtml

Comment: That didn't work :/

Comment: I changed the following line to:         

<?php $_u = 'p[url]=' . $_productUrl . '&p[images][0]=' . $_productImageUrl . '&p[title]=' . $_productName . '&p[summary]=' . urlencode(trim($_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description'))); ?>

TO:

        <?php $_u = 'p[url]=' . $_productUrl . '&p[images][0]=' . $_productImageUrl . '&p[title]=' . $_productName . '&p[summary]=' . urlencode(trim($_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($this->htmlEscape($_product->getShortDescription())), 'short_description'))); ?>

Comment: is it not  work?

Comment: No. Where should I add htmlEscape function?

Comment: Still the same problem. Adding htmlEscape didn't change anything!

Comment: remove nl2br function

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this still requires an answer however your problem is because you have not implemented Facebook's OpenGraph Tags...If more information is required please reply here